# line between the numerator and the denominator

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call the line in a fraction? It is a horizontal line that is between the numerator and the denominator.

[image: https://s14.postimg.org/7gpwuavwh/fraction_cool.png]

Suggestions:

- vinculum
- solidus
- fraction line
- fraction bar
- fraction stroke
  *shilling stroke

I admit that sometimes it can have a shape of a slash, so it doesn't have to be horizontal.

Comment: there seems to be no agreed upon term. Some typographers seem to call is a *fraction slash*: http://superuser.com/questions/922074/difference-between-unicode-fraction-slash-and-division-slash/922075.

Comment: I think "stroke" for this is mainly a UK usage.

Comment: @Silenus: if there is uncertainty as to the terminology, perhaps the previous question that Edwin Ashworth found should be reopened?

Comment: @suməlic I don't agree. General reference.

Comment: @Rathony: what is the general reference? The only free online dictionary I've found that says "vinculum" can be used with this meaning is [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vinculum), the dictionary that anyone can edit. Also, even Wiktionary suggests that this usage is confined to Australia. Other sources say only that the word "vinculum" referred to a horizontal line used to *group* terms together, not to indicate the operation of division. Even if "vinculum" can be used to indicate the division line, there might be a better word or a more internationally common word.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://jeff560.tripod.com/fractions.html) we see the terminology:

> horizontal fraction bar, vinculum

and

> diagonal fraction bar, solidus, virgule

So if you want to include both, just say "fraction bar".